# I do not load the data when Ionic 3 and Json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I want to load all the films I do not load them, the page goes blank and I want to know how to solve so that all the movies load me.
This the service.ts

```
getAll(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+value);

    console.log('value: ' + headers);

    this.http.get(this.global.apiUrl+'/movies', {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(result => {
        resolve(result);
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  })

});
```

}

This is the function that I am loading in home.ts

```
    getMovies() {
    //let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({});
   // loading.present();

    this.ms.getAll()
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log(result.data.length);

            var movie = result.data;
            this.movies.push(movie);


        if (this.infiniteScroll) {
          this.infiniteScroll.complete();
          if (this.movies.length == result.total) {
            this.infiniteScroll.enable(true);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        this.toast.create({ message: 'Erro ao listar os usuários. Erro: ' + error.error, position: 'botton', duration: 3000 }).present();
      });
  }
```

Comment: can you reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-chj9ye

Comment: Do you get any output in your console?